# How to install a font onto cygwin terminal

Tags: fonts, cygwin

I really like Dejavu font. And I want to make it available on cygwin terminal. But I don't know how to install this font. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I don't know how to install this font

1. Open the folder containing the `.ttf` files using `explorer`.
2. Right click on the font file and select "Install".

Note:

- You can install multiple fonts at the the time by selecting them, then right click and select "Install".

  [image]

---

#### I want to make them available in the Cygwin terminal.

To use these font in the Cygwin `minty` terminal:

1. Right click on the `minty` title bar, then click "Options".

   [image]
2. Select "Text" on the left side, then click the "Select" button.

   [image]
3. Select the DejaVu font you want using the font selection dialog.

   [image]
4. Press "OK" twice.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  After installing new fonts in Windows 8, the list of fonts in the mintty dialog does not change.  I click on "Show more fonts" but am unable to change anything.

Comment: Have you tried running as Administrator?

Comment: Thanks for your response!  1) I meant to say Windows 7.  2) Tried running as Administrator but still didn't see any new fonts and wasn't able to do anything after clicking "Show more fonts".  3) In Control Panel -> Fonts -> Font settings, I unchecked "Hide fonts based on language settings" and more fonts were visible within Cygwin, but not all of them.  :-/

Comment: Hmm. It works fine here with Windows 7. What font are you trying to use? Can you use the font in other programs?

Comment: @hourback It looks like you can only use **fixed-pitch** fonts.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I was trying to use Roboto.  I typed that into my .minttyrc and it loaded, but didn't look great.  :-)  I guess that's what's happening, that the list of fonts is being filtered (?).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @hourback Yes, it is being filtered to show only fixed-pitch fonts

Comment: I had some trouble picking the correct font name, and realised, the one to use is not the file-name, nor the name shown in the font-list, but rather the name shown in the font-preview window. See https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/507#issuecomment-358638708

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, specifically I wanted to use Roboto Mono with mintty. I had the font installed but it didn't show up in mintty's font selection dialog. Upon further digging I found this helpful tip on mintty's github page:

> To provide additional fonts for use with mintty, monospace fonts can be installed in Windows. Note that font installation in X11 does not make a font available for mintty as mintty is not an X windows application. **Some monospace fonts are not explicitly marked as such in the font file.** In that case the font will not be listed in the mintty Options – Text – Font selection menu. It  an still be used by explicit selection, e.g.:
>
> `mintty -o Font="Linux Libertine Mono"`

On my particular box I edited the launch options of mintty as follows:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -o Font="Roboto Mono" -
```